# MySQL function that finds the occurence of certain character and returns an integer?

Tags: mysql, sql, string, integer, position

I use MySQL, and I constantly struggle to find a fuction that returns an int of a char from a string where I can change the occurence of the chosen char.

INSTR() returns the position of the first occurence, but thats it I can't add parameters to change occurence like in substring_index. Cause this is how currently do it, but I think i am making it way to complex.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    producent,
    LEFT(RIGHT(producent,
            LENGTH(producent) - INSTR(producent, 'O') + 1),
        INSTR(producent, 'E') - INSTR(producent, 'O') + 1) AS O_tot_E
FROM
    bordspellen
WHERE
    INSTR(producent, 'E') > INSTR(producent, 'O')
        AND INSTR(producent, 'O')
        AND INSTR(producent, 'E')
ORDER BY producent;
```

[image]

The query above does what I want, but I simpy am looking for a function explained in the description above.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really make the question clearer.

Comment: How do I share sample data?

Comment: yes, please add sample data and desired results.  it is very hard to see what you mean.  your query seems to be finding the characters between the first O and the first E?  and it sounds like you are wanting to possibly look between the second O and a following E or something?

Comment: the best way to share sample data is to create a fiddle, using e.g. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 with create table and insert statements, followed by whatever query you have tried and then just edit your question to add the url.   That also helps us know what version you are using

Answer (score 0):

You can use `regexp_substr()`:

```
select regexp_substr(col, 'o[^e]+e')
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler query that does more or less the same thing as yours is just:

```
select
    producent,
    regexp_substr(producent,'O[^E]*E')
from bordspellen
```

though that finds the E after an O and doesn't reject rows where there's also an E before the O.  You may want `'O[^OE]*E'` and/or `+` instead of `*`.  regexp_substr requires mysql 8.0 or mariadb 10.0.

I don't know what your "returns an int of a char" or "change occurence" meant, and the data you showed did not seem likely to be your real problem.  You will get better answers if you show your real data.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=032b9385c711d45853bdb0d6ca5ee24c)